# why solidity 0.5.0 version code does not verify on etherscan?

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan

The solidity version 0.5.0 at v0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a seems some issue while verifying at Etherscan.io

The contract I deployed:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0ebeb14d4af5459a74c845e56947a37a9143cba0#code

Is compiling well in remix, but exact same parameters used in verifying at etherscan, and it is not verifying.

So, is there any issue in solidity 0.5.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although etherscan says, "If contract compiled at remix, will compile here", but it seems there is an issue in solidity compiler version 0.5.0 at etherscan.

I verified many contracts using previous version older than 0.5.0, but when I tried to verify a simple contract using compiler version 0.5.0, then it did not generated byte code. Even though the same contract compiled in remix.

I searched for more information, but could not find it. So, just be patient. And it will be resolved after some time.

Comment: Ok lets wait till it fix

Comment: If you find a bug, you should consider reporting it to etherscan. It won't get fixed if they don't know it exists

Comment: Yes sent them bug report.. Thanks for the comment and lets see if that fix before 0.5.1  haha

Comment: They fixed it.. Etherscan team is awesome.. It is working now..
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x81fd082410e3f1a6f1e158399d726b1ae3956880#code